# Is this a nest and which wasp species?

Tags: species-identification, wasps

A friend found this stuck to his insect screen today.
He said it felt like dust.
This wasp/bee was alive.
Location is Germany.
Is this a nest?

First look:
[image: first]
After peeling it open:
[image: second]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a **European wool carder bee** (*Anthidium manicatum*)

More precisely a female, judging by the round end of the abdomen.

[image: Anthidium manicatum]

Information regarding the nest it was found in:

> These bees construct their nests in preexisting cavities, using the trichomes of wooly plants.
>
> Females use their mandibles, which are sharply toothed, to remove trichomes from the stems and leaves of various plants. They then roll up the trichomes into a ball and bring them to a preexisting cavity. Inside the cavity, the bees fashion the trichome ball into cells, where they deposit an egg as well as a provisioning mass consisting of nectar and pollen. Once finished, she seals the entrance to the cavity with a terminal plug, which consists of inorganic and organic materials that she brings to the nest. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthidium_manicatum)

[image: Wooly plant]